# What is the earliest version that suppprts iPhone Wifi Assist equivalent for Android?

Tags: wi-fi, android-versions

On my iPhone I have something called [Wifi Assist](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205296):

> With iOS 9 and later, you can use Wi-Fi Assist to automatically switch to cellular when you have poor a Wi-Fi connection.

What is the first Android version that supports this natively?

Comment: I assume Lollipop (that's where I start to see the " WiFi has no internet connection" hints), though I don't have concrete proof yet.

Comment: There are posts indicating that Samsung had this before Lollipop but based on this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/91462/3573 really its all about switching a setting (or changing tolerance) for RSSI (signal strength) which 
 isn't quite as clear cut since the value will vary between one handset maker and another due to the different radios used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently Google implemented it in 2014 in Android, and you couldn't properly disable it. Not even today.

I believe this feature is baked into Android.

Windows 8.1 definitely had it in 2014 according to this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10652/windows-phone-cellular-and-sim-settings I'm pretty sure Windows Phones predating this also had it although documentation seems lacking.

Wi-fi assist was introduced in iOS 9(2015). https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205296

There are apps for Android that do this but at least this one is 3rd party. No sources says it predates 2015. I have not experimented enough with this on Android. https://www.guidingtech.com/54831/get-ios-like-wi-fi-assist-android-using-speedify/